# How to queryset filter with two or more lists?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I want to make a filter with two or more lists, to my model

For example: 
I'm trying to do it like that

```
from django.db.models import Q

rq = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'...]

transact = Transact.objects.filter( Q(request__in=rq) | Q(area__in=rq))
```

But it does not work just take the second option, in this case it is `area`

something like that, but with lists

`Transact.objects.filter(Q(request='c')| Q(area='d'))`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want both of them to be getting evaluated?

Comment: @Rarblack yes, that is I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q is equivalent to `OR` in SQL language. If you desired to find the intersection value of `request__in=rq` and `area__in=rq` you should use ordinary filter mechanism which is equivalent to `AND` clause.

```
rq = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'...]

transact = Transact.objects.filter(request__in=rq,area__in=rq)
```

**EDIT:** Instead of using Q(because this is not the solution for what you ask) you can use this approach:

```
rq = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'...]
result = Transact.objects.filter(request__iregex=r'(' + '|'.join(rq) + ')', area__iregex=r'(' + '|'.join(rq) + ')')
```

Comment: I'm sorry I did not respond well before, if I want a `OR`

Comment: Then you are saying it is only returning the value according to the second clause. Logically filter cannot return value according to the both it will choose the latter one if both are correct

Comment: Try to explain what you really are trying to do so I can help you on that.

Comment: What I want to achieve is something like that, but in this case using lists, I hope you understand me `Transact.objects.filter(Q(request='c')| Q(area='d'))` If I do not find the first one, look for it for the second

Comment: Try the edited answer hope it will help you otherwise your code is correct there is nothing to fix in that.

Comment: Great I'm going to try it